# I want to change the background image in a downloaded bootstrap theme

Tags: bootstrap-4

[below is the code. I want to insert an image from the local computer but it is not accepting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iplaq.png)

Comment: Please post the code inline instead of linking to an image.

Comment: Please read this before posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the http request to your localhost.